# mysql how to recognize between pure number and mixed number/letter without a function?

Tags: mysql, regex

In MySQL database, I have a column in a table that has both pure numbers or mix number/letters. There's no pattern, and I want to distinguish if it's pure number, and flag it as `true`, otherwise `false`. Is there a good method I can use? I tried:

```
ID REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$',
ID REGEXP '[0-9]+',
   REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z.]+$',
   REGEXP '[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*2[^0-9]*3[^0-9]*4[^0-9]*5[^0-9]*'
```

**Column:**

```
2A0000BY
4A00A0BF.1
12345678
12345679.1
300000BE
123456FD
3S435F40
```

Comment: What was wrong with what you tried?  What happened?

Comment: Do you mean "number" as in `12.34`?  Or "digit" as in `1`?  Your attempts seem to allow "digits", but not some "numbers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using something like the following to match numbers. If not, it means it has some letters:

```
ID REGEXP '^[\-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$'
```

You can also do that without using REGEX, like this:

```
CONCAT('',ID * 1) = ID
```

You can test the full queries for both approaches [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ffdd/8).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CASE statement along with regexp during a SELECT statement.

Something like this might work: it returns true/1 for every "id" entry that is only numbers, and false/0 otherwise:

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE 
     WHEN id regexp '^[0-9.]*$' THEN true
     ELSE false
  END AS is_only_numbers
FROM strings;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demonstrating](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c40b/17)

Comment: `12345679.1` is a "number" by this test; is that what the OP wanted?

Comment: Not sure, honestly. Easy to change, though, just remove the "." Character from the regex.